# Parsing List inside a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below json , and want parse it in flutter , it is list inside list

https://run.mocky.io/v3/00aabcdf-69e6-45c2-89fa-aef9619878e1 .

Below in my service class i am calling getUserDetails and then hitting the mock api to get the object . This method will return the List of model which has the leave related
details also . How can i parse that .

My Modal Class

```
            import 'package:basefl/models/leavemodal.dart';
            
            import 'approvedallowedleaves.dart';
            
            class UserDetailsModal {
              final String userId;
              final List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves> leavesApproved;
              final List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves> leavesAlloted;
              final List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves> leaveRemaining;
            
              const UserDetailsModal(
                  {required this.userId,
                  required this.leavesApproved,
                  required this.leavesAlloted,
                  required this.leaveRemaining});
            
              factory UserDetailsModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                return UserDetailsModal(
                    userId: json['userId'],
                    leavesApproved: json['leavesApproved'],
                    leavesAlloted: json['leavesAlloted'],
                    leaveRemaining: json['leaveRemaining']);
              }
            
              // factory EachLeaves.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
              //   return EachLeaves(leavetype: json['leavetype'], days: json['days']);
              // }
            }
```

My Service Class

```
            import 'package:basefl/models/leavemodal.dart';
            import 'package:basefl/models/userdetailsmodal.dart';
            import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
            import 'dart:async';
            import 'dart:convert';
            import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
            
            class LeaveService {
              
              UserDetailsModal parseUserDetails(String responseBody) {
                final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
                return jsonDecode(responseBody)
                    .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
                    .map<UserDetailsModal>((json) => UserDetailsModal.fromJson(json))
                    .toList();
              }
            
              Future<UserDetailsModal> getUserDetails(String userId) async {
                final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
                    'https://run.mocky.io/v3/00aabcdf-69e6-45c2-89fa-aef9619878e1'));
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  return compute(parseUserDetails, response.body);
                } else {
                  throw Exception('Unable to Get the Attendance.');
                }
              }
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the **ApprovedAllowedLeaves** model in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method fromJson should look like this:

```
factory UserDetailModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserDetailModal(
    userId: json["userId"],
    leavesApproved: List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves>.from(json["leavesApproved"].map((x) => ApprovedAllowedLeaves.fromJson(x))),
    leavesAlloted: List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves>.from(json["leavesAlloted"].map((x) => ApprovedAllowedLeaves.fromJson(x))),
    leaveRemaining: List<ApprovedAllowedLeaves>.from(json["leaveRemaining"].map((x) => ApprovedAllowedLeaves.fromJson(x))),
);
```

And you also should write a modal class for ApprovedAllowedLeaves